# Difficulties with an example 1.9 of The C Programming Language

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm am working my way through the exercises of the first chapter of *The C Programming Language* and while I understand most of what is said and shown, there is one example that I don't understand.

In 1.9, there is a function shown to return the length of a line while setting a char array, passed as an argument, to the contents.

```c
int get_line(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i, l;

    for (i = 0, l = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        if (i < lim - 1)
            s[l++] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n')
        if (l < lim - 1)
            s[l++] = c;
    s[l] = '\0';

    return l;
}
```

The thing I do not understand, is why we need this: `if (c == '\n') {...}`. Could this not be combined in the for-loop? Where we explicitly check that `c` is not equal to `'\n'`? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why this needs to be an external condition.

Any light shed would be helpful!
Thanks!

Comment: It will help us to answer if you suggest an alternative code that does the same without that last condition.

Comment: You'd make it more concise with the `break` keyword.  But that's explained in chapter 3, the example is from chapter 1.  Writing programming books is not that easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put it in the loop, you have to do something like that:

```
int get_line(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i, l;

    for (i = 0, l = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) {
        if ((i < lim - 1) && (c != '\n'))
            s[l++] = c;
        else if (c == '\n') {
            if (l < lim - 1)
                s[l++] = c;
             break;
         }
    }

    s[l] = '\0';

    return l;
}
```

So as you see, wrapping the condition inside the loop, led to more conditions checks and a `break` statatement.

Comment: That makes sense! I guess I don't really understand why we need to include the `'\n'` in the first place. But that has more to do with the program than with the actual code. But your example made it very clear that it is desirable to keep it out of the loop. Thanks!

Comment: @ReinVanImschoot Because the code is supposed to read a _line_. So it has to stop when a _new_ line begins (`\n` is the newline character).

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop is exited if either `c` equals `EOF` or `c` equals `'\n'`. Therefore, immediately after the `for` loop, if you want to know which value `c` has, you must test.

Answer (score 2):

> is why we need this: `if (c == '\n') {...}`.

`get_line()` is structurally:

```
get_line() {
  initialize

  while get, A not true and B not true
    perform X

  if B
    perform X
  
  finalize
```

The loop quits under 2 conditions.  With one of those (`c == '\n'`), we still want to perform `X` *somewhere*  as that is part of the function goal.

---

> ​Could this not be combined in the for-loop?

It  could be  combined, yet then we have 2 locations that exit the loop.

Typical coding guidelines promote a single location to quit the loop.  If we set aside that goal, then:

```
get_line() {
  initialize

  while get, A not true
    perform X
    if B quit the loop
  
  finalize
```

As below with the *same number* of conditions checks, yet 2 loop exit points.

```
int get_line(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i, l;

    for (i = 0, l = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) {
        if (i < lim - 1)
            s[l++] = c;
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
    }

    s[l] = '\0';
    return l;
}
```

We could contort the code to get the 2 checks back on the same line and not have that pesky *after the loop* `if (c == '\n')`.  Stylistically this may be harder to follow.

```
int get_line(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i, l;

    for (i = 0, l = 0, c = 0; c != '\n' && (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) {
        if (i < lim - 1)
            s[l++] = c;
    }
    s[l] = '\0';

    return l;
}
```

Lastly, code could use improvements:

- No need for `i` and `l` index counters.  One is enough.
- Array sizing and index best uses `size_t` type.  Warning: `size_t` is some *unsigned* type.
- Using a leading size parameter allows for better static code analysis and self-documenting code:  the `lim` relates to `s[]`.
- Avoid math on input parameters to not incur overflow.  We have more range control on local objects.
- Careful when `lim` is at an extreme or zero.
- Rather than assign after declaration, where practical, initialize.  E.g. `int i = 0;`

---

```
get_line() {
  initialize

  while B not true, get, A not true
    perform X
  
  finalize
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
      
size_t get_line(size_t size, char s[size]) {
  int ch = 0;
  size_t i = 0;

  while (ch != '\n' && (ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (i + 1 < size)
      s[i++] = (char) ch;
  }

  // size might have been pathologically 0, so no room for \0
  if (i < size) {
    s[i] = '\0';
  }
  return i;
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand how some people think that two exit points in a loop could be less readable. It more clearly expresses what's going on that the original, and the DRY aspect helps readability also.

Comment: @Elliott I also do not see 2 clear exits as an issue.  Yet for learners, multiple exits tend to lead to poor code - so consider a single exit a goal and not a rule.  As with many coding practices, they are not "Thou shall not do this" and are more like "Avoid this unless that".

Comment: @Elliott On a separate point, the `int ch = 0; ... while (ch != '\n' && (ch = getchar()) != EOF) { ... }` idiom is something I conjured up for this answer.  Hope it does not look too weird.  I did like how it shortened code.